# Can methods that return const reference or references cause memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am extremely curious if returning a reference from a method can cause a memory leak. Below is the example situation.

```
class example
{
public:
  vector<int> & get_vect()
  {
     return vect;
  }
  int & get_num()
  {
    return num;
  }
private:
  vector<int> vect;
  int num;
};


void test_run(example & input)
{ 
   int & test_val = input.get_num();
   vector<int> & test_vect = input.get_vect();
}

int main()
{
  example one;
  test_run(one);
  return 0;
}
```

My question is when `test_val` and `test_vect` get removed from the stack when `test_run` exits. Does either `test_vect` or `test_val` get deleted thereby causing the object one to get corrupted?

Comment: A memory leak can only ever occur if dynamic memory allocation is involved.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. References are aliases (or *names*) for something else. You can think of it as a *never-owning* pointer to something without pointer semantics (and their pitfalls, though references themselves have a few twists).

When the function `test_run` exits, the references and only them are gone. What they referred to hasn't been touched memory-wise, it hasn't been deleted.

Moreover, as you're only dealing with variables that have automatic storage duration and don't involve dynamic memory during construction, you simply can't have memory leaks there. You could have other problems like trying to delete a pointer that points to such variable (trying that just yielded a **[core dump on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3598dfa3f890889)**) but not leaks.

Answer (score 8):

**No.** Why should it cause a *memory leak*, if you are not allocating memory with `new`, which means on the *heap*? All your variables are allocated on the *stack*. References are just *aliases* for other variables.

C++ reference definition according to `wikipedia`:

> The definition of a reference in C++ is such that it does not need to
>   exist. It can be implemented as a new name for an existing object.

There's also a [paragraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29#Relationship_to_pointers) talking about the difference between pointers and references.