# Where does the reference points to?

Tags: c++, memory-address

I'm not sure if I have understood the stack right. I have the following operator
overloading for the complex numbers a and b (a=3+5i and b=2+i).

```
struct complex{
int x;
int y;
};

complex& operator+=(complex& a, const complex b){
a.x=a.x+b.x;
a.y=a.y+b.y;
return a; 
}
```

now i wonder where does the reference for the return value points to.

I think in the main stack frame there is a memory area for a = a.x and
a.y of 64 Bits because a.x/a.y are of type int. And the return value a
in the operator+=stack-frame points to this "a"-memory area.

I wonder how the "a"-memory-area looks like and how is an object of
the type complex is stored in the main-stack-frame?

Is it like an array and the reference points to "a[0]“ or are a.x and
a.y separeted and you need "two" reference-pointers to point to an
object of type complex.

Comment: The returned reference doesn't *point* anywhere at all, but it does *reference* whatever you passed as the first argument. And how references are implemented, or how structures are stored, it's implementation specific, and may differ from compiler to compiler. And why does the structure have to be on the stack? What if you pass a dereferenced pointer to a heap-allocated memory area?

Comment: Don't confuse references and pointers, they're not the same, [though they share somewhat related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25810732/1594913).

Comment: In principle, your members `a.x` and `a.y` lie as they were an array (`struct complex{int x[2];}` would be the same assembly code, as I know). But this is what the compiler do. Not what you can use in your C/C++ Code.

Comment: @Matthias: That's likely but not guaranteed.

Comment: @Susliks: The `const` in `const complex b` seems misplaced. It's legal, but fairly useless. Did you perhaps mean `const complex& b`?

Comment: If you are using Visual C++ you may let your compiler write an assambly file, where you can read what your data will looks like in the memmory. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6.aspx If your code is not optimized, the data might look like, I have written. (But I can not give any garantie). If your compiler do some optimization, then it will be very hard to make any speculations.

Comment: You should focus on how the standard treats the behaviour of a reference, not how it is implemented by various vendors on various platforms. Having said that, you should treat the returned reference `r = a + b`"as if" it was `a` after an update, where `a` might have been declared as `complex a;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is a reference to the variable used to invoke the `operator +=` with.

```
complex w, p;

void f() {
  w.x = w.y = 0;
  p.x = 1; 
  p.y = 0;
  w += p;
}
```

the parameter `a` on `operator +=` is an alias for `w`, and the parameter `b` is an alias for `p`.

Answer (score 1):

Memory map of a complex object looks like a collection of memory address and it will be implementation dependent . Array definition is only guaranteed to hold a continuous memory locations. Memory lay out of a complex object need not be allocated in continuous memory locations.

Return address of operator over loaded function should be the address of the first object complex object  a  as per your implementation.